# NX Schematics, how to call own schematic

Tags: angular-schematics, nrwl-nx

I can't find how to use a newly created schematics with NX using `ng g workspace-schematic <schematic-name>`

Here is my structure :

```html
|- tools/
  |- schematics
   |- my-first-schematic
   |- my-second-schematic
```

I want to use `my-first-schematic` within `my-second-schematic`.
I know about `externalSchematic()` but it's useful when we want to call schematif from another collection.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

we can directly import *my-first-schematic* into *my-second-schematic* and then chain it simply.
e.g.

tools/schematics/my-first-schematics/index.ts

```
export default function(schema: any): Rule {
    console.log('my-first-schematics');
}
```

tools/schematics/my-second-schematic/index.ts

```
 import myFirstSchematics from '../my-first-schematics';

 export default function(schema: any): Rule {
     console.log('my-second-schematic');
     ...
     return chain([
         myFirstSchematics(schema),
         ...
     ]);
 }
```